# Calling thread cannot access object because different thread owns it

Tags: wpf, multithreading

I thought I knew what causes this exception until I wrote this:

```
var menu = ViewConfigHelper.CreateObjectFromResource<Menu>(config, baseURI);
if (!menu.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
{
    throw new ArgumentException("Somethign wrong");
}
if (!LayoutRoot.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
{
    throw new ArgumentException("SOmethign wrong");
}
 // exception throw here
LayoutRoot.Children.Insert(0, menu);
```

First line creates a Menu control from an embedded XAML file. Both CheckAccess calls return true.  However, when last line is executed, an exception is thrown with the message "Caling thread cannot access object because differrent thread owns it."  The code above is being executed within a method called immediately after InitializeComponent() that created LayoutRoot, on the same thread, I believe.

Someone please enlighten me.  I am trying to create a multiple UI thread WPF app.

Comment: Why not just write `LayoutRoot.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => Layout.Children.Insert(0, menu);`in the last line

Comment: Did not think of that.  Was busy thinking of why problem is occurring.  Will try this if i cannot find an answer but I may be masking a real problem..... Also, if menu and LayoutRoot were not created on same thread, I doubt, this would work.

Comment: Conrad, suggestion throws same exception.  What is even more interesting is that LayoutRoot and menu reference the same dispatcher and thread!  A StatusBar or ToolbarTray does not throw this exception.

Answer (score 4):

You are using CheckAccess() in reverse. You want to lose the ! signs before each check. See the example bit of code on the [CheckAccess()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.checkaccess.aspx) MSDN page.

In the Winforms world you'd do a InvokeRequired() which is now the same thing as a !CheckAccess(). In your case because both values are returning true, and you are inverting them, neither if block is hit.

**To expand a bit**... in the Winforms world, the normal patter was:

```
if(InvokeRequired)
{
    Invoke(...);
}
else
{
    //do work
}
```

(or sometimes a return after invoke, if it was invoking the same method).

In WPF, CheckAccess() is similar to, but not identical to InvokeRequired... there for a pattern more along the lines of:

```
if (someUiControl.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
{
    //Doing an update from this thread is safe, so we can do so here.
}
else
{
    // This thread does not have access to the UI thread.
    // Call the update thread via a Dispatcher.BeginInvoke() call.
}
```

The key difference between is that InvokeRequired() returning true meant it was UNSAFE to do the update in the current thread... while a true from CheckAccess() means it is SAFE.

Comment: Sorry, I do not get it.  What do you mean by calling a method in reverse?

Comment: I have expanded my answer to try to clear things up a bit better.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Yes, a true from CheckAccess() means it is safe. Neither ArgumentException is thrown which means both the menu and LayoutRoot (grid) are owned by same thread.  So, while I appreciate your response, it does not explain what I am observing.  Also, this problem occurs only when adding a menu to the grid.  Adding a ToolbarTray, under the same circumstance, does not throw this exception so it appears to be a WPF related bug with creating menus under multi-UI threading scenarios.  NOTE, this only happens when I am trying to create a window on a seperate "UI" thread.